# Speeding up applying mapping to an image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an RGB to a gray-value image of the same size (with values between 0 and 1). The mapping is done by a dictionary called `MASK_LUT_IDX` which takes in a tuple (RGB) and returns the corresponding value. The current code is 2x faster than before, but still takes 1.5s (according to `timeit`), which is proving to be an issue.

```
import numpy as np

def quickConv(numpy_triple):
    return MASK_LUT_IDX[tuple(numpy_triple)]

def ImageSegmenter(masked_img):
    rgb_tuples = np.array(masked_img.getdata(), dtype=tuple)
    class_idxs = np.apply_along_axis(quickConv, 1,rgb_tuples)
    return np.array(class_idxs).reshape(masked_img.size[1],masked_img.size[0])


class_img = ImageSegmenter(masked_img)
```

Is there a better way of converting this? I've looked into the palette functionalities, but it doesn't seem to quite fit my needs.

Comment: A dictionary is not the way to go. It would be faster to use a 3D lookup table, which you index using something like `lut(img[0], img[1], img[2])`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 3D LUT? Do you mean store the scalars in a tensor and index it using the RGB value

Comment: Ok, a quick google search lead me to this: https://pillow-lut-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, you can call a 3D array a tensor. I just think of an array with three indices, one for red, one for green, one for blue. The package you link could be a solution. You can also do it using a plain 3D NumPy array.

Comment: How would you do that? I tried ```rgb_tuples = np.array(masked_img.getdata())
    class_idxs = FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX[rgb_tuples]``` and keep getting "Unable to allocate array with shape (3, 307200, 256, 256) and data type float64".

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, please read [mre], it'll help us communicate better. But if `FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX` is your 3D array, then you need 3 indices, not one. As I said in the first comment, you need to index similar to `lut[img[0], img[1], img[2]]`.

Comment: My bad, I just realized what you meant by lut[img[0], img[1],img[2]]. To get it to work over the entire image I wound up using lut[img[:,:,0], etc..]. It sped things up alot, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Cris Luengo's help, here is a sped up version of the function.

```
def ImageSegmenter(masked_img):
    masked_img = np.array(masked_img)
    class_idxs = FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX[masked_img[:,:,0],masked_img[:,:,1],masked_img[:,:,2]]
    return class_idxs
```

Where FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX is a 3d tensor set given by

```
FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX = np.zeros((256,256,256))
for idx,label in zip(CLASS_IDX,CLASS_LABELS):
    red_idx = RGB_CLASS_MAPPING[label]['R']
    green_idx = RGB_CLASS_MAPPING[label]['G']
    blue_idx = RGB_CLASS_MAPPING[label]['B']
    FASTER_MASK_LUT_IDX[red_idx,green_idx,blue_idx] = idx/NUM_CLASSES
```

RGB_CLASS_MAPPING maps an RGB value to a class, which was unrolled using enumerate to create CLASS_IDX and CLASS_LABELS using a list comprehension.

```
CLASS_IDX,CLASS_LABELS = zip(*[(idx,label for idx,label in enumerate(RGB_CLASS_MAPPING)])
```